# Transições CSS em menu expansível

Tags: css, menu

Tendo um menu expansível como usar a transição CSS para abrir/fechar **ao mesmo tempo** a parte que está aberta e a parte que está a fechar?

O problema não se põe no caso de os menus terem o mesmo tamanho [**(exemplo)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qHqf/1/), mas quando o tamanho é diferente dá ideia que o CSS lê o `max-height` como o valor real e não como um máximo...

Exemplo do problema aqui:  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qHqf/)

---

**HTML**

```html
<div class="max">
    <ul class="menu">Pequena
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">Pequena
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">Grande
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
        <li>Ten!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.max ul {
    border:2px solid #a5f;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:20px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.max ul.opened {
   max-height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definindo a altura de cada `<li>` como zero por padrão(defeito), você pode definir a altura como `20px` quando estiver `.opened`, mesmo não tendo exatamente o mesmo efeito visual

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qHqf/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Já que você está usando o Javascript pra adicionar a classe, porque não usa por exmeplo um jQuery pra fazer isso? 
Você não trabalharia o tamanho fixo...e então se comportariam como um acordeon..

**HTML:**

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        Pequeno
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
        Grande
        <ul>
             <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
            <li>Seven</li>
            <li>Eight</li>
            <li>Nine</li>
            <li>Ten!</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```javascript
$("ul li").click(function(){
    //Quando clica esconde QUALQUER que estiver aberta
    $("ul li ul:visible").slideUp();
    //Abre a que possui hierarquia com a que você clicou:
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle(); 
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdhp8/)**

Comment: Vinicius, obrigado, eu sei como fazer usando Javascript (Mootools no meu caso), mas eu queria usar só CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Você está encontrando esse problema de atraso na animação por causa da propriedade `max-height`.

Observe que no seu Fiddle, se você substituir o `max-height` pelo `height` o problema não acontece. (Apesar do layout ficar diferente do que você quer, provavelmente.)

O atraso é causado por que o Browser interpola a propriedade `max-height` do valor `250px` ao valor `20px` no intervalo de um segundo. Como `250px` é maior do que a altura "efetiva" do elemento, existe um atraso até que o valor da propriedade `max-height` seja menor que a altura do elemento para que ele comece a ser "cortado".

Pelo que eu sei, nenhum browser atualmente é capaz de interpolar corretamente entre um valor especifico de `max-height`, como `20px` e o valor automático, `default`. (O Google Chrome interpola `20px` com `0px`, e então exibe a altura gerada pelo valor `default`, enquanto o Firefox desativa a transição CSS totalmente.)

Infelizmente será provavelmente necessário especificar a altura exata por elemento, ou usar um outro efeito se você deseja fazer isso só com CSS.

Comment: Marco, obrigado por ter dado uma olhada ao problema. Eu estou consciente do problema estar relacionado com o max-height, o que eu estranho ( e procuro uma solução ) é, porque é que o CSS começa a animação do valor máximo e não do valor real onde o `ul` parou a abretura. Uma vez que não abre até 250px porque começar a animação pelos 250px?

Comment: Se você usar o *Web Inspector* para observar o estilo computado do `<div>` com ele aberto, o valor de `max-height` estará em `250px`. (O que está sendo animado é o `max-height` e não o `height` diretamente.) Concordo que é confuso, pois fica difícil visualizar o valor do `max-height` diretamente...

Comment: Correcto, mas se eu não defino o `heigth` e o ul não abre até aos 250px, esperaria que a transição começasse por volta dos 80px (o valor real). Se eu usar `document.querySelectorAll('.menu')[1].clientHeight;` para obter o valor do heigth recebo 80px, que eu não defeni mas ainda assim a transição parou ali.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, fiz um exemplo com o evento hover por ser mais prático!

Não sei se a inclusão de uma nova classe é o ideal, fica menos dinâmico.

**HTML:**

```html
<ul class="max">
<li class="menu">Pequena
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu">Pequena
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu gr">Grande
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
        <li>Ten!</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.max{
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.max > li{
    height: 18px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border:2px solid #a5f;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;    
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay:0.15s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.15s;
    -o-transition-delay:0.15s;
    transition-delay:0.15s;
}

.max > li:hover{
    height: 80px;
}

.max > li.gr:hover{
    height: 215px;
}

.max > li ul li{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Veja o **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qHqf/4/)**

Comment: Oi Luiz, obrigado por ter dado uma olhada ao problema. A sua solução não resolve o problema, simplesment o disfarça usando uma velocidade de transição mais rápido e um max-height mais baixo.

Comment: Olá Sérgio, realmente não é a solução ideal. Tentei trabalhar utilizando a sua abordagem mas não obtive sucesso! Fica como uma alternativa. Mas espero que consiga solucionar. Irei acompanhar as novidades! abs